# XPages DojoCombobox user is not allowed to enter a value which is not in the list

Tags: combobox, dojo, xpages

1. I have created a dojo combobox with dojo (djCombobox),
   [image: That combobox should look like this]
2. I get values in to combobox which works very well. I added a screenshot how it should look like...
3. But user can also enter a value that is not in the list.

It should look like in the picture above and a user cannot be entered a value which is not in the combobox list. How can i do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `<xe:djFilteringSelect id="djFilteringSelect1"></xe:djFilteringSelect>` instead of a combobox.